# home page of my site is not appear in google search, when I type site:example.com

Tags: google, htaccess, google-search-console, google-search, google-index

I am totally confused, when I place `site:example.com` in google I see every page of my website in serp(search engine result page) except the home page. I don’t know why it’s happening but I check everything according to google SEO rule. But not getting success.I try to check my site through google webmaster tool everything is perfect there,
Please help me to solve this.

htaccess rule of my site

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.ro/.*$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?exa-example.ro/.*$ [NC]
#RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|swf|flv|png)$ / [F]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^privacy_policy.html$ privacy.php
RewriteRule ^contact_us.html$ contact.php 

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sitename.com$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitename.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)_([0-9]+).html$ articol.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+).html$ categorii.php?abbr=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9+]+)$ search.php?cuvinte=$1
RewriteRule ^images/$ images [F]
RewriteRule ^o_articole/$ o_articole [F]
```

Comment: What does webmaster tools report about your sitemap? How many URLs submitted / how many indexed?

Comment: the report is ok and homepage is already indexed by google but not shoing in the serp when you type site:example.com in google

Comment: That does seem a bit strange?! Searching for `"30 years since an amazing video game"` returns your homepage at #2 in the SERPs, but searching for `site:[www.]example.com "30 years since an amazing video game"` does not return anything. (?)

Comment: Looks like the internal search engine in your CMS creating duplicate content problem and can affect on your homepage ranking.

Comment: i am not about keyword worried ranking, i am worried about why my site is not appearing when i type site:mario--games.com. every page is there except the homepage.

Comment: Please ***do not*** ask similar questions on multiple sites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413280/home-page-of-my-site-is-not-appear-in-google-search-when-i-type-siteabc-com). Choose one site and ask your question there. This question is on-topic here and off-topic over at stack overflow, so I've flagged the stack overflow question for moderation action.

Comment: sorry for that. I will follow the rule in future. Actually I was so worried that's why i post this question in so many places.

Comment: Have you ever found out what was the cause of this issue? Did the appearance of your homepage in site:example.com returned?

Answer (score 5):

The home page of your site is indexed and cached by Google and appears in search results.

See this screenshot of a search including a string of text taken from your page:

[image]

Remember that a "site:" search in Google doesn't necessarily show all the pages that have been indexed, and that the order of pages doesn't reflect the "value" of each page.

Comment: but every site have this except mine. Can you please explain me why it's happen

Comment: You do have a number of potential issues with your site. I would expect there to be some information in Google Webmaster Tools is something was wrong. You need to check everything there - how often the site is index, when the last time was, if there was any issues.

Also perhaps correct your robots.txt so that it contains:
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Comment: no in webmaster they are perfect and google send a good certificate when I use reconsideration service. But till now the site is not coming through site: