# Single page not appearing in Google Search

Tags: seo, google, google-search, google-index

### Description

I have a static franchise website which has various sub pages each dedicated to an individual franchisee.

For each franchisee the page, the only thing slightly similar between all of them are the page titles, they follow this structure:

```
<title>
  Welcome to THE_COMPANY - PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION Services, THE_LOCATION
</title>
```

**THE_COMPANY** and **PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION** are the same across all franchisees, however **THE_LOCATION** changes depeding on where they are located in the UK.

Each franchisee page has the following `<meta />` tags:

```
<meta name="DC.creator" content="user"/>
<meta name="DC.format" content="text/html"/>
<meta name="DC.language" content="en"/>
<meta name="DC.date.modified" content="2014-01-23T11:22:31+00:00"/>
<meta name="DC.date.created" content="2014-01-23T11:22:09+00:00"/>
<meta name="DC.type" content="Page"/>
<meta name="DC.distribution" content="Global"/>
<meta name="robots" content="ALL"/>
<meta name="distribution" content="Global"/>
```

The main content on each franchisee page is completely different.

### The Problem

There is one particular franchisee page, located in *Area A*.. Which will **not** appear in Google Search results at all. However every single other franchisee (if you Google Search for "**THE_COMPANY**, **THE_LOCATION**" is number 1). And if I do the same search on Bing, Yahoo or DuckDuckGo, the **Area A** franchisee is the first result on all of them.

Has Google for some reason black listed one page on the site?

### What I Have Tried

- Ensuring the page is referenced in my **sitemap.xml** file
- 'Fetching as Google Bot' the link www.the_company.co.uk/areaa

  - When that came back as **OK** I would submit to index
- Resubmitting the **sitemap.xml** file in Webmaster Tools
- Linking to the **Area A** page from another pages content

  - For this I also waited about 3 weeks before checking again to give Google time to re-index
- Making a change to the page content and waiting another 2 / 3 weeks
- Removing the page completely and recreating it with an alternative URL

The closest thing I have found to this issue is [this StackOverflow question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/home-page-of-my-site-is-not-appear-in-google-search-when-i-type-siteexample-co)
but this particular franchisee has existed for almost a year, it used to appear on Google searches however no longer does. I'm guessing the [Panda update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) wasn't too happy with something on the page, but it hasn't effected anything else on the site and I am at a loss for things to try.

I would greatly appreciate any information or thoughts as to what could have caused this

Thanks.

### Update

In line with Daniel Fukudas answer below, I have followed some of his steps but everything seems to check out alright:

**HTTP Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Date => Tue, 25 Feb 2014 16:31:29 GMT
Server => Zope/(2.12.16, python 2.6.6, linux2) ZServer/1.1
Content-Length => 40078
Expires => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type => text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language => en
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Connection => close
```

**Robots `<meta />` tag**:

```
<meta name="robots" content="ALL"/>
```

I have updated this `<meta />` tag to read `content="INDEX"` instead now.

**robots.txt**:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*sendto_form$
Disallow: /*folder_factories$
```

**Using site:THE_COMPANY.co.uk**:

Searching for 'AREA A site:THE_COMPANY.co.uk' does not return the page, but regardless of that searching just for **site:THE_COMPANY.co.uk** will not necessarily return every indexed page, or so I understand...

### Update

It appears Google likes to drop pages every now and then from the index, despite my steps above, I left the site alone and the page appeared back in the SERPs by itself.

Comment: Do you get any error when you fetch it as Google? If it fetched successfully, you should be able to 'submit' it.

Comment: @vDog I have submitted it a couple of times after fetching (fetching comes back as 'OK'), apologies I forgot to write that in my original question. But it still will not appear in search results.

Comment: Dan. All you can do is make sure that the page/site is okay and that the search spider can index the page. The rest is up to the search engine. Google can do some funny things from time to time. It may take as much as 60 days under normal conditions before your page shows up. I would reset your site to how it should be, stop pinging Google (I know it's hard...), and wait. It could be that there is an issue that has nothing to do with you at Google and you may be exacerbating the issue. It is not too unusual that Google does not index the full site. Not right away.

Comment: @closetnoc I will refrain from doing much else to possibly make the situation worse, however the page originally did appear in results and mysteriously vanished.. It has been up for around 1 year, and appearing in search results up until around the time Panda came out (that might be a coincidence as there's no black hat stuff going on here).

Comment: Sometimes a page is indexed, but does not show up in the SERPs unless a very specific search query is made using site: and unique keywords. Try that. I have seen something like this even recently but it has always worked out. It may be a recent adjustment on Google's side that makes the page hard to find. When I see these, it is a matter of time before Google makes another adjustment and the page reappears. I am not sure this is the case for you. But like I said Google can do funny things from time to time. My experience is that it will work itself out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

- that page returns code 200 @ HTTP headers. Check `X-Robots-Tag`.
  You can check headers here: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php
- that `meta name="robots"` on that particular got `content="all"` or `content="index"`
- to check *robots.txt*
- inspect your website @ Google using `site:example.com`

Comment: Unfortunately everything seems to check out, I have updated my question to reflect the points you raised, please see the "UPDATE" heading