# Homepage isn't appearing anywhere when searching site:example.com

Tags: google-search, search-results

When doing google search with `site:www.example.com` the homepage can't be found anywhere in the returned results. It used to come as first result till a few days ago.

At the same time, a regular search for the site's domain it brings the home page as main result, including the famous Google site main links below.

In **Webmasters Tools** I can'f find any culprit, page is accessible, craw-able, indexable. I also re-submitted the page and removed some old ulrs from Google's index that no-longer exist and were redirecting to the homepage.

**Has anyone ever experienced this? Why is this happening and what it might mean?**

---

> **Supplementary notes**
>   I did some search before writing my question and didn't find anything.
>   However, when I finished it, I found this 3 years old question:
>   **[home page of my site is not appear in google search, when I type site:example.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/home-page-of-my-site-is-not-appear-in-google-search-when-i-type-siteexample-co)**
>
> However, it doesn't seem to have an answer, nor the OP ever returned
>   to post back if he managed to find the cause and the solution on that.
>
> Maybe after 3 years, there might be more webmasters in this site that
>   have experienced this, so we can get a good valuable answer.
>
> To be honest, I suspect this can be something temporary and that the
>   homepage will return back in this type of search, yet it is a weird
>   situation that makes me scratch my head.

Comment: What happens when you search for a sentence from the home page in quotes?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: If I use the H1 of the home page to search for in quotes, I get the home page as result

Comment: Then you don't have a problem.   `site:` searches are not guaranteed to return results in any particular order or to contain every page from your site.